# HTTPS request from javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app

How to send https request to address https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me from java script and most important how to get data from server?

I need it to identify users e-mail in my packaged chrome app.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this would violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Additionally, the whole point of HTTPS is so that the whole page (and request cycle) is secure.

The alternatives would be:

1. Make the request using [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/), or
2. Set up a proxy: let your JS call your own server on the same origin,
   which will in turn make an HTTPS request, or
3. Have an iframe which points to an HTTPS page (on your own server).  This page should then be able to make Ajax requests to the server over HTTPS.  Using the HTML5 postMessage API, you can then post a message back to the parent window.

Comment: tried JSONP and got following error: Refused to load the script 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?responseText=jQuery203001675232592970133_1391892045713&q=select+*&format=json&_=1391892045714' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Is this via a Chrome extension, Chrome web app, or your own script?

Comment: yes, I'm writing packaged chrome app and what to get users email address in mu app.

Comment: It looks like your app is violating Content Security Policy (CSP) (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).  Have you made your app CSP compliant, by giving it the proper permissions?  Specifically, as the error suggests, did you add the "script-src" to the "content_security_policy" in the manifest file?

Comment: added this "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me; object-src 'self'" to manifest. didn't help. same error.